# Generating files by programming in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

Suppose I have some data in the `_data` folder from which I want to automatically generate pages. That is: imagine `_data/structure.md` is something as follows

```
chapters:
  -
    chapter1  
    chapter2 
    chapter3 
    ...
```

and I need static files `chapter1.md`, `chapter2.md` ... and so on which are quite similar in structure (for instance, `chapter1.md` is

```
---
title:chapter1
layout: default
---

This is chapter1!!
```

). **Is there a way to create these files automatically, without doing them by hand, just changing or adding items in the `_data` file?**

Comment: Is content (like "This is chapter1!!") needs to be different for all files ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel Different but depending only on the parameter `chapter1`, that is, there is no more info needed than what `_data` contains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generator ([documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/generators/)).
This can be something like this :

```
module Jekyll

  class DataPage < Page
    def initialize(site, base, dir, name)
      @site = site
      @base = base
      @dir = dir
      @name = name
      self.process(@name)
      self.data ||= {}
      self.data['layout'] = 'default'
      self.data['title'] = data
    end
  end

  class CategoryPageGenerator < Generator
    def generate(site)
      datas = site.data['structure']
      datas.each do |data|
        name = "#{data}.md"
        page = Jekyll::DataPage.new(site, site.source, @dir, name)
        page.data['title'] = data
        page.data['layout'] = 'default'
        page.content = "This is #{data}"
        site.pages << page
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Works fine!! What about doing exactly the same, but saving the generated files in a specific folder? (that is, `_site/chapters` instead of `_site`) I guess some extra piece of code is needed

Comment: in `initialize` : `@dir = 'chapters'`