# Generate Markdown Posts in Jekyll and Made Available to Paginator Variable

Tags: ruby, api, jekyll, jekyll-paginator

Is it possible to generate a set of posts in _posts as Markdown files in a way that they are treated as if they had been manually created and therefore, available to the process of creating the site pagination? I found examples of how to generate pages in various places like this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37207189/generating-files-by-programming-in-jekyll), but they seem to put the rendered content in _site and displaying the {{ paginator.total_pages }} variable does not yield any value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to add "dynamic" content using a [generator plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators).

You can generate pages, posts, collection's items, static files, anything you want.

For the `{{ paginator.total_pages }}` returning nothing. The `paginator` variable will only be available in your [pagination template](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/) and nowhere else.